# gzip/mod_deflate does not work on apache2, ubuntu, amazon ec2

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gzip, mod-deflate

I have tried everything and I cannot get gzip or mod_deflate to work. I have placed almost everything into my .htaccess file as well as my apache2.conf file. They all do not work.

Here is my server configuration:

Amazon EC2 with everything forced to `https://www.` with Apache (apache2) and Ubuntu. Every time I run my website through an online tester, it says that my gzip is not working/enabled. I checked multiple times and my mod_deflate and my mod_filter are both installed and enabled and running.

I've also restarted my server and restarted apache a few times but it still does not recognize that my files are gzip'ed. Here's one of the multiple codes I've tried to add from gtmetrix:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

I ran my website through gtmetrix and it says my .js files and my .css files are not compressed through gzip. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my index is a .php page so I had to add this in my index.php page:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Comment: by any chance, you remember how did you figure this out?